# git is not detecting changes in some files

Tags: git, msysgit

I have managed to get my index in state where some files aren't tracked as expected.

As an example I have size.h and test.h unmodified in the working directory:

```
$ git-ls-files -st size.h test.h
H 100644 de2c741b07d86f92bdd660626848072cb2bf510f 0     size.h
H 100644 8bb24bc7483ffcfc0fc1a3761dc63e86a1b3e003 0     test.h
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Then I do some random change to both files:

```
$ fortune >> size.h
$ fortune >> test.h
```

For some reason size.h is not modified (although the file clearly is). At the same time test.h is modified as expected:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   test.h
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

After removing the index and resetting everything is back to normal:

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       size.h
M       test.h
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   size.h
#       modified:   test.h
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have been working with git 1.6.6 on CentOS and msysgit 1.6.5.1 on Windows over samba on this repository before the strangeness appeared. I have not been able to reproduce this from a fresh clone.

My gut feeling is that this is a bug in msysgit, maybe in combination with samba. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The only bug I have seen which also display the wrong status for a Git over samba is the [GitX ticket 147](http://gitx.lighthouseapp.com/projects/17830/tickets/147).
It is about an opposite situation (git status shows modification for a file which has not been modified), but suggests that some elements of the file (size? date? rights?) are not properly transmitted through the samba share.

> This made me wonder wether this was a clock problem on the computer. Setting the time on the server to `-1h` does not help.
>   BTW, gitx and git-gui work perfectly through sshfs on the same two machines (but, even though convenient, sshfs is not as fast as samba on a local network).

[Locking issue](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=130) has been known to happen when cloning a repo over samba share.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this problem with version 1.7.9.msysgit.0

The problem was that I had moved the project to a new directory, and atleast one of my submodules had an absolute path for the worktree.

Once I removed the submodule directories, deleted their entries in .git/modules, and re-initialized and updated them, the problem went away.

This was odd because git gave absolutly no error or warning message (that I could see) when checking status of the project, only when I did a git submodule update --init would it show me the error that it couldn't get to the path it wanted to.